# not allow duplicates in a pureComputed element

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Having this element (note the computed field) `fullNumber`

```
var NumberField = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.maskFormat = "0";
  self.firstNumber = ko.observable("");
  self.secondNumber = ko.observable("");
  self.thirdNumber = ko.observable("");
  self.fourthNumber = ko.observable("");
  self.fifthNumber = ko.observable("");

  self.fullNumber = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return [
      self.firstNumber,
      self.secondNumber,
      self.thirdNumber,
      self.fourthNumber,
      self.fifthNumber ].map(ko.unwrap);
  }
}
```

Then I use it like:

```
<div class="numberFields" data-bind="with: numbers">

  <input id="0" class="number-ball" maxlength="2" type="tel" data-bind="twoDigits: firstNumber, maxNumber: 68">
  <input id="1" class="number-ball" maxlength="2" type="tel" data-bind="twoDigits: secondNumber, maxNumber: 68">
  <input id="2" class="number-ball" maxlength="2" type="tel" data-bind="twoDigits: thirdNumber, maxNumber: 68">
  <input id="3" class="number-ball" maxlength="2" type="tel" data-bind="twoDigits: fourthNumber, maxNumber: 68">
  <input id="4" class="number-ball" maxlength="2" type="tel" data-bind="twoDigits: fifthNumber, maxNumber: 68">

</div>
```

How can I ensure there are no duplicated values in `fullNumber`?

Comment: What do you want to do when there *is* a duplicate? Replace it? Return `null`?

Comment: @user3297291 simply leave it blank (or null), please also check update, I added html also

Comment: underscore js has the uniq function. http://underscorejs.org/   _.uniq([1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3]);
=> [1, 2, 4, 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your computed you can chain all kinds of functions that `map` over your numbers. Essentially, you're doing three things:

1. Move from `observable` to `Number` by calling `ko.unwrap`,
2. Check if the unwrapped value already exists, i.e.: filter uniques
3. Make sure there are no ugly `null` or `undefined` values in your array that could result from empty inputs

In plain javascript, but with some "modern" features (`Array.from`, `Set`):

```js
var uniques = function(arr) {
   // There are many implementations of a unique method.
   // google/search for `unique js values` to learn more
   return Array.from(new Set(arr));
};

var arrUnwrap = function(arr) {
  return arr.map(ko.unwrap);
};

var truethyValues = function(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(val) {
    return val;
  });
};

var NumberField = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.maskFormat = "0";
  self.firstNumber = ko.observable("");
  self.secondNumber = ko.observable("");
  self.thirdNumber = ko.observable("");
  self.fourthNumber = ko.observable("");
  self.fifthNumber = ko.observable("");
  
  var numbers = [
      self.firstNumber,
      self.secondNumber,
      self.thirdNumber,
      self.fourthNumber,
      self.fifthNumber ];
  
  
  // Read from right to left: 
  //  fullNumber is: unwrapped, unique, truethy numbers
  self.fullNumber = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return truethyValues(uniques(arrUnwrap(numbers)));
  });
}
                                    
ko.applyBindings(new NumberField());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input data-bind="textInput: firstNumber">
  <input data-bind="textInput: secondNumber">
  <input data-bind="textInput: thirdNumber">
  <input data-bind="textInput: fourthNumber">
  <input data-bind="textInput: fifthNumber">
</div>

<h1 data-bind="text: fullNumber"></h1>
```